# HTML script shows different on my browser

Tags: html

When I uploaded the html & css parts into webhost, on my browser (Google Chrome) didn't show all of the page, so I deleted cache, media, everything.

Tried to enter again on the website, still wasn't loaded all of the page.

I enter to website by Mozilla, page was there, full loaded.

Asked my friend to enter by chrome to my website, page was full loaded

I tried to enter again by chrome to website, page wasn't full loaded.

Restarted my pc,  tried again, page wasn't full loaded.

But why?

That's how only I see from Chrome

[image: That's how only I see from Chrome]

That's how everybody sees even if it's from Chrome or another browser

[image: That's how everybody sees even if it's from Chrome or another browser]

Missing code :

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-main">
            <div class="col-md-6 banner-left">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/ba.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 blc-layer3-grids-3 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                <span class="bann-heart"></span>
                <h2>OFERTA SPECIALA ! </h2>
                <hr>                <br>
                <h1>Reducere MAJORĂ LA <font style="color:red">UNIVERSAL GAIN FAST !</font></h1>
                <hr>
                <h2 class="item_price"><strike>$200.00</strike></h5>
                <h2 class="item_price"><strong>$100.00</strong></h5>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure that it isn't cache? If it is not about cache and only YOU see it different, then it must be a Chrome extension that you have installed.

Comment: @RezaSaadati It's logic that if only I see that it must be something local. I don't have any extensions / my cache's are clear, something is because of my localhost but I don't know what, I mean, another websites are working fine, another directories are loading up fine, why that? I don't know if it's something about scripting there, maybe bcause of browser but I deleted everything

Comment: Have you checked that the HTML is valid, e.g. with [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, fixed some errors which it show me, (ex i had h2 then closing tag was h5)  but still error was showing

Comment: @NewbieHTML Another thing you can try is to append something to the URL, e.g. if the page you want to see is "http://www.example.com/index.html" then use "http://www.example.com/index.html?x=1". Any caching that is happening in between your browser and the web server should think that it is a different page and so fetch fresh data from the server.

Comment: @NewbieHTML Also, invoke the developer tools (i.e. press F12) and look in the "console" section for any errors such as `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://emindesign.ro/templates/GymPlate/shopping/js/move-top.js”`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I mentained my PC shut for 5 minutes and now it works, idk why, i don't know if it was cache (because it was empty). Thank you for your time, all of you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Caches for Too Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550715/chrome-caches-for-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue but then i realised that was due to cache.

How i found was, i re-uoloaded the file to another directory and everything worked fine. Sometimes chrome is a bad guy with cache issue.

Probably try deleting cache again or reload the page with shift pressed several times.

Comment: Tried that. I added in public_html instead of  public_html/directory.  Still page wasn't loading ok. (Inspect element and div was missing, it wasn't there) Deleted cache, restarted PC, still didn't work,  the full div is missing.

Comment: Any chance if your local server is switched on and you have any dependence issue ? If so try switching off your local server (wamp/xamp, etc)

Comment: Yep, it was switched on (Because I'm working on localhost then uploading it on webhost, but when I restarted my PC it automatically switched off, and browser wasn't loading either.  This is the website, I still see it without that div.  https://emindesign.ro/templates/GymPlate/shopping/